# Django: "field specifies a many-to-many relation through model which has not been installed" error

Tags: python, django, django-models

After splitting a `models.py` file containing 3 models, into 3 different files, I got the following error when running `make migrations` or `migrate`:

> (models.E022) .resolve_through_model at
>   0x105d74e18> contains a lazy reference to products.itemsbyarticle, but
>   app 'products' doesn't provide model 'itemsbyarticle'.
>   products.Article.items: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many
>   relation through model 'ItemsByArticle', which has not been installed.

Project structure is: my_project > products > models > [article.py | item.py | items_by_article.py]

**article.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):

    items = models.ManyToManyField('products.Item', through='ItemsByArticle', blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=_('items'))
```

*NOTE: I tried `through='products.ItemsByArticle'` instead, same error.*

**item.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # ...
```

**items_by_article.py**

```
class ItemsByArticle(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('article', 'item')

    article = models.ForeignKey('products.Article',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey('products.Item',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             verbose_name=_('item'))
```

Curiously, when running unit tests (and Django creates a new database), there is no error.

Comment: probably you have to use through='products.ItemsByArticle'

Comment: @bmons already tried, same error :(

Answer (score 3):

Do you have **`__init__.py`** file in `my_project/products/models/` which [imports all models of the module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package)?

```
from .article import Article
from .item import Item
from .items_by_article import ItemsByArticle
```